# UPDATE column to MIN of a SELECT result set - what went wrong?

Tags: sql-server, select, update

I've got the following scenario:

I've got

- a table of assets with standard columns
- a table of hardware assets with extension columns
- a history table where all changes to an asset are stored with asset ID, field name, date, new value
- a contact table

I want to set a field in hardware assets called "first_usage" to **the earliest date of change** of the contact field (called "resource_contact") when the new value was a contact with a user-ID (i.e. no technical user or group).

One difficulty was that no ID is stored in the "new value" but  a combined string of first, middle and last name (in case change of contact).

My first try of a query looks like this:

```
UPDATE  dbo.asset_z_hardware 
SET     first_usage = (
        select min(history.com_dt) 
from    dbo.nr_com              history, 
        dbo.ca_contact          contact
where   history.attr_name = 'resource_contact' AND      
        history.com_par_id = own_resource_uuid AND
        contact.userid IS NOT NULL AND
        (history.new_value = '' + 
            case when contact.last_name     is not null then        contact.last_name   end +
            case when contact.first_name    is not null then ', ' + contact.first_name  end +
            case when contact.middle_name   is not null then ' '  + contact.middle_name end
        )
)
```

This seemed to work quite OK, though only some assets were updated with a date (probably I need to check the string-comparison and contacts which changed meanwhile).

But then I realized that I only should update **only active assets**! The "inactive" flag is in the main asset table called "ca_owned_resource". 
Unfortunately, after adding the new condition, the first usage values were **all set to the same date**!!! How come? I did not find my mistake.

This is the second query with "inactive" flag and link between hardware and main asset:

```
UPDATE  dbo.asset_z_hardware 
SET     first_usage = (
        select min(history.com_dt) 
from    dbo.nr_com              history, 
        dbo.ca_contact          contact, 
        dbo.ca_owned_resource   res
where   history.attr_name = 'resource_contact' AND
        res.inactive = 0 AND res.own_resource_uuid = own_resource_uuid AND
        history.com_par_id = own_resource_uuid AND
        contact.userid IS NOT NULL AND
        (history.new_value = '' + 
            case when contact.last_name     is not null then        contact.last_name   end +
            case when contact.first_name    is not null then ', ' + contact.first_name  end +
            case when contact.middle_name   is not null then ' '  + contact.middle_name end
         )      
 )
```

I'd appreciate any help and suggestions for the only-one-date-mistake, also for improving the rest, if any ideas.

Comment: Try with explicit JOIN syntax and also reference all the columns in the where clause with the alias prefix and see if your results change. Also, if I were doing the testing, I would run the select version of the query before the UPDATE...

Comment: Alternately, run in a transaction that you roll back, and use the OUTPUT clause to see what would be changed.

Comment: user1443098, Thanks for the hint with transaction. If it was in live or pre-live system, this would be a good idea! Fortunately I've got a separate dev system. But I'll keep that in mind! --- Jacob H, the join would not bring a difference, maybe in performance or readability, I already marked the right answer. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because it thinks that `own_resource_uuid` in your sub-query is `res.own_resource_uuid`, not `asset_z_hardware.own_resource_uuid`. If you specify it completely, it should be unambiguous and SQL will know what you intended.

Before you introduced `res` there was nothing else it could be. SQL will assume you mean a column in the local sub-query if there’s one there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. First I thought it would be unneccessary, cause "own_resource-uuid" is a FK from asset_z_hardware to res and thus it's the same value. But I was wrong, this was the cause of having always the same date! Thanx!